# How to avoid the calling of same function multiple times?

Tags: iphone, ios5, gps, xcode4.2, core-location

I am using core location framework inside my app.The didUpdateToLocation method is called two times when app starts very first time.I allocated location manager instance and initiate it and called startUpdatingLocation. And in didUpdateToLocation i am calling another function in which i am sending the current latitude and longitude to server so how can i avoid multiple calling of this function?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
if( [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    locationManager.delegate = self;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    locationManager.distanceFilter = 1000.0f;

else
{
    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"GPS Disabled"          message:@"Enable GPS settings to allow the application to search for your current location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alertView show];
    [alertView release];
}
}

  //Here is didUpdateToLocation method

 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
      fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
   {
  self.lat = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
  self.longi = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"Updated Location : lat--%f long--%f",self.lat,self.longi);
   [self updateUserLocation];



  }

  //in this function i am sending the latitude and longitude to server.
 -(void)updateUserLocation
 {

   NSString *urlString = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://appifylabs.com/tracemybuddies/index.php/iphone/updateUserLocation/?userId=1&latitude=%@&longitude=%@",self.lat,self.longi] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

[conn url_Connection:urlString withActivityView:self.activityView     withParentView:self.view];
  }
```

Comment: once you got the locations in update method, call the stopUpdating method, which stops the updating..

Comment: put your code here what you are doing.. it will make to understand clear..

Comment: i cannot do this because i need the current location updates inside my app and every time when current location get update i am sending the updated latitude and longitude to server. This function is get calling  two times only when app starts first time otherwise didUpdateToLocation method get called only once when current location is updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside didUpdateToLocation, when oldLocation is received as NULL, return from the function.
It will be NULL when first time your delegate will be called.

Second, you can take the difference of time stamp between currentTime and newLocation.timeStamp. If it is not with in acceptable limit, return from the function.

Comment: Thanks, i am checking in didUpdateToLocation method if oldLocation is equal to NULL then return from the function.its solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should call your server only if a certain timeinterval has elapsed ?

```
int now = (int)[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

if(now - self.lastUpdate > INTERVAL_BETWEEN_TWO_UPDATES) {  
    [self callServeur];
    self.lastUpdate = now;
}
```